# Dealing with php array whose content may or may not have another array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I am dealing with arrays whose structure is different depending on the number or items in the array.

For example, the following is the array with one item in it.

```
// Case #1
["Assignment"]=>
object(stdClass)#29 (9) {
  ["Id"]=> string(10) "1234567890"
  ..
}
```

However if there are more than 1 item in the array,

```
// Case #2
["Assignment"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#28 (9) {
      ["Id"]=> string(10) "1234567890"
      ..
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#28 (9) {
      ["Id"]=> string(10) "1234567890"
      ..
    }
  }
```

Notice that the contents are in another array for this. No matter of how many items there are, I want to access the `Id`. `$array->Id` will work for one case but won't work for the other with the error saying, `Trying to get property of non-object`.

I could come up with an inefficient way by counting the # of contents in the array like this:

```
// say the arrays above are declared as $assignment
if($numOfAssignment > 1) {
  foreach($assignment as $key) {
    echo $key->Id;
  }
}
else { 
  echo $assignment->Id;
}
```

But if the code was a bit lengthy, I feel it is too repetitive and inefficient.
Is there a way to do this in one effective phrase no matter of the number of the contents inside the array? Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

Comment: Use `is_array()` to test whether the element is an array or not.

Comment: If ['Assignment'] holds an array you need to iterate it anyway so each element can be accounted for. This means you have to check if it's an array or not.

Comment: it should be foreach($assignment as $key => $value) {
    echo $key:$value;
  }

Comment: @Barmar How to test whether the element is an array or not is not my question. My question is: for either case that the array's element has an array or not, how can I access the element in one united way. The reason is if I check `if(is_array()) do sth; else do sth;` it is basically two phrases with same functionality. And if a phrase is lengthy, it feels like being inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is change the non-array into an array with a single element, then you can process it consistently.

```
if (!is_array($assignment)) {
    $assignment = array($assignment);
}
foreach ($assignment as $key) {
    echo $key=>Id;
}
```